# Problema al crear vista: Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, tengo un problema en un proyecto ASP.NET MVC, el cual al momento de querer crear la vista desde el .cs de la carpeta Controllers, me aparece un mensaje `El valor -1 no se encuentra en el intervalo aceptable`.

Lo intenté hacer desde la propia carpeta de "Views" pero tampoco fue posible. Probé re-compilar e incluso volí a crear el proyecto desde cero, pero no dio resultado, por favor solicito de su ayuda, gracias por la atenación.

[image: Creación de la vista]

Answer (score 0):

En ese código hay algunos problemas.El encabezado de la acción Index anterior debe ser [HttpGet] en lugar de [HttpPost]. Lo estás creando con agregar nueva vista sobre el método?
Por favor, postea tu código fuente.

Sin embargo, el error que te aparece es de configuración, aquí hay un problema relacionado en otro hilo para que pruebes si te funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599/cant-add-view-from-controller-in-vs-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-sele/51944868#51944868

Comment: Es cierto, ya corregí a [HttpGet] agradezco la observación
Revisaré el link para hacer pruebas.
Gracias